# Resize RichTextBox width to fit the text in a specified maximum height

Tags: .net, vb.net, controls

I have a `RichTextBox`, a maximum height and a variable width.

I'd like to resize the box width, in order to fit all the text in without having a scrollbar.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can get if the control has scroll bars with this:

```
Public Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Integer) As Integer
```

And then call a function like this one after changing the text:

```
Private Sub ValidateTextBox(tb As RichTextBox)
    Dim Hdl As IntPtr = tb.Handle
    Dim Style, VBar As Integer

    tb.Width = iMinWidth
    Style = GetWindowLong(Hdl, GWL_STYLE)
    VBar = Style And WS_VSCROLL

    While VBar > 0 AndAlso tb.Width < iMaxWidth
        tb.Width += 24

        Style = GetWindowLong(Hdl, GWL_STYLE)
        VBar = Style And WS_VSCROLL
    End While
End Sub

Public Const WS_VSCROLL As Integer = &H200000
Public Const GWL_STYLE As Integer = (-16)
```